# Shall I use req.user or req.session.passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using Passport for logging users in Nodejs. But when I tried to access the user by req.user, I get: Promise { pending } 
However, I can get the users id with req.session.passport.user.id - Is it fine to do it that way?

This is the promise, how can I improve it?

```
const getUserBy = async (what, type) => {

    const poolConnection =  mysql.createPool({
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'root',
        password: 'password',
        port: 3306,
        database: 'mydb'
    });


    //FIND THE USER AND RETURN IT
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){

        poolConnection.getConnection((err, con) => {

            if(err) resolve(false)

            con.query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE " + type + " = ? LIMIT 1", [what], (err, row) => {

                if(err) resolve(false)

                //If there were no rows found
                if(row.length != 1) resolve(null)

                //Resolve the user found
                resolve(row[0])

            })

        })

    })

}



/* INITIALIZE PASSPORT TO RETURN */
const initialize = (passport) => {

    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {

        const user = await getUserBy(email, "EMAIL")

        if(user == false) return done(null, false, {message: "Unable to find this user"});

        if(user == null) return done(null, false, {message: "This account and password don't match"});

        //Check if the password match the database
        const foundPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if(!foundPass) return done(null, false, { message: "This account and password don't match" })

        return done(null, user)

    }

    passport.use(new LocalStratergy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser));

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => done(null, getUserBy(id, "ID")))

}
```

I am not very sure if I should get the user using a promise, but it was the only way I made it work.